# Can payment for reserved instances sold on AWS marketplace be converted to AWS credit?

Tags: amazon-web-services

This would be very useful since only US bank accounts are supported.

Thanks,
Graeme

Answer (score 1):

From AWS Support:

> Hello,
>
> Thank you for contacting AWS.  My name is Sadie and I would be happy
>   to help you out today.
>
> I wish I was going to be able to help you more but currently US bank
>   accounts are the only way we have to pay sellers for their RI's. I
>   wish it was just as simple as being able to turn it into AWS credits.
>   However, at this time this is not possible.
>
> I apologize for the inconvenience.
>
> Best regards,
>
> Sadie G.